# using pd.to_datetime to form a date by taking input of year,months,day present in different columns in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a problem combining the day month year columns to form a date column in a data frame using pd.to_datetime. Below is the dataframe,i'm working on and the columns Yr,Mo,Dy represents as year month day.

```
data = pd.read_table("/ALabs/wind.data",sep = ',')
Yr  Mo  Dy  RPT     VAL     ROS    KIL      
61  1   1   15.04   14.96   13.17  9.29
61  1   2   14.71   NaN     10.83  6.50 
61  1   3   18.50   16.88   12.33   10.13
```

So I've tried the below code, i get the following error: "to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing"

Step 1:

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data[['Yr','Mo','Dy']],format="%y-%m-%d")
```

Next I've tried converting  Yr,Mo,Dy column datatype to datetime64 from int64  and assigning the result to new columns Year,Month,Day. Now when i try to combine the columns i'm getting the proper date format in the new date column and i have no idea how i got the desired result.

Step2:

```
data['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Yr,format='%y').dt.year
data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Mo,format='%m').dt.month
data['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Dy,format ='%d').dt.day
data['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(data[['Year','Month','Day']])
```

Result:

```
Yr  Mo  Dy  Year Month Day  Date
61  1   1   2061    1   1   2061-01-01
61  1   2   2061    1   2   2061-01-02
61  1   3   2061    1   3   2061-01-03
61  1   4   2061    1   4   2061-01-04
```

But if i try doing the same method by changing the column names from year,month, day to Yy,Mh,Di like in the below code. I get the same error "to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing"

Step3:

```
data['Yy'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Yr,format='%y').dt.year
data['Mh'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Mo,format='%m').dt.month
data['Di'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Dy,format ='%d').dt.day
data['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(data[['Yy','Mh','Di']])
```

**What i want to know :**

1) Is it mandatory for the argument names to be 'Year' 'Month' 'Day' if we are using pd.to_datetime?

2) Is there any other way to combine the columns in a dataframe to form a date, rather than using this long method?

3) Is this error specific only to python version 3.7??

4)where have i gone wrong in Step 1 and Step 3 ,and why i'm getting o/p when i follow step 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [`pandas.to_datetime` docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime), the column names really do have to be `'year'`, `'month'`, and `'day'` (capitalizing the first letter is fine). This explains the answer to all of your questions, and no it has nothing to do with the version of Python (and all recent versions of Pandas behave the same).

Also, you should be aware that when you call `to_datetime` with a sequence of columns (as opposed to a single column/list of strings), the `format` argument seems to be ignored. So you'll need to normalize your years (to `1961` or `2061` or `1061`, etc) yourself. Here's a complete example of how you could do the conversion in a single line:

```
import pandas as pd

d = '''Yr  Mo  Dy  RPT     VAL     ROS    KIL      
61  1   1   15.04   14.96   13.17  9.29
61  1   2   14.71   NaN     10.83  6.50 
61  1   3   18.50   16.88   12.33   10.13  '''
data = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(d), sep='\s+')

dtime = pd.to_datetime({k:data[c]+v for c,k,v in zip(('Yr', 'Mo', 'Dy'), ('Year', 'Month', 'Day'), (1900, 0, 0))})
print(dtime)
```

Output:

```
0   1961-01-01
1   1961-01-02
2   1961-01-03
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

In the above code, instead of adding the appropriately named columns to the dataframe `data`, I just made a dict where the key/value pairs are eg. `('Year', data['Yr'])`, and also added `1900` to the years.

You can simplify the dict comprehension a bit by just adding `1900` directly to the appropriate column:

```
data['Yr'] += 1900
dtime = pd.to_datetime({k:data[c] for c,k in zip(('Yr', 'Mo', 'Dy'), ('year', 'month', 'day'))})
```

This code will have the same output as the previous.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how Python deals with years, but the reason it wasn't working had to do with the fact that you were using the year 61.

This works for me

```
d = {'Day': ["1", "2","3"],
     'Month': ["1", "1","1"],
     'Year':["61", "61", "61"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df["Year"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Year"])
df.Year = df.Year+2000
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year','Month','Day']], format='%Y%m%d')
```